# Django views: optimize code

Tags: django, django-views

I have a problem with my views.py. I repeat a lot of code, I wonder if it is possible to optimize.

Here is my code:

Profile:

```
def profile(request, id):
    if 'person' in request.session:

        me = Users.objects.get(pk=session)

        total_songs = songs.count()
        total_fans = fans.count()
        total_friends = amigos.count()

        total_storage = porcentajeAlmacenamiento(me);
        storage_left = almacenamientoRestante(me);
        notifications = Notification.objects.all().filter(receptor=session, leido=0)
        total_notifications = notifications.count()

        return render_to_response("profile.html", {
            'total_amigos': total_amigos, 
            'total_fans': total_fans,
            'total_songs': total_songs, 
            'me': me,
            'total_storage': total_storage,
            'storage_left': storage_left,
            'notificaciones': notificaciones,
            'total_notifications': total_notifications},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

Home:

```
def home(request):
    if 'person' in request.session:

        me = Users.objects.get(pk=mi_session)
        songs = Song.objects.filter(autor__in = Friend.objects.filter(usuario=yo).values_list('amigo', flat=True)).order_by('-fecha_subida')
        comments = Comment.objects.all().filter(cancion__in=canciones)

        total_songs = songs.count()
        total_fans = fans.count()
        total_friends = amigos.count()

        total_storage = porcentajeAlmacenamiento(me);
        storage_left = almacenamientoRestante(me);
        notifications = Notification.objects.all().filter(receptor=session, leido=0)
        total_notifications = notifications.count()

        return render_to_response('index.html', {
            'total_friends': total_friends, 
            'total_fans': total_fans,
            'total_songs': total_songs,
            'total_storage': total_storage,
            'storage_left': storage_left,
            'me': me,
            'comments': comments,
            'notifications': notifications,
            'total_notifications': total_notifications,
            'songs': songs}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

As you can see, there is a part of code that repeats into almost all views:

```
  total_songs = songs.count()
  total_fans = fans.count()
  total_friends = amigos.count()

  total_storage = porcentajeAlmacenamiento(me);
  storage_left = almacenamientoRestante(me);
  notifications = Notification.objects.all().filter(receptor=session, leido=0)
  total_notifications = notifications.count()
```

Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Thanks

Comment: just extract it into a method, and return a dictionary

Comment: How I can concatenate this dictionary to the other parameters?

Comment: what other parameters are we refering to here ?

Comment: { 'comments': comments, 'songs': songs, + DICTIONARY }

Comment: { 'comments': comments, 'songs': songs }.update(DICTIONARY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way would be to make a function returning a dictionary.
In your view you would create a dictionary with the remaining keys, and you would just do something along the following lines:

```
general_data = get_general_dict() # the redundant keys
specific_data = {'comments':comments, etc.)
specific_data.update(general_data)
return render_to_response('index.html', specific_data, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```